# Send ArrayList<Integer> between Bundle

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

Problem:
How do I transfer the data of `_selectednumber`  and `_points` from `onSaveInstanceState` to `onRestoreInstanceState`?

```
private List<Integer> _selectednumber= new ArrayList<>();
private List<Integer> _points = new ArrayList<>();
private int _hit= 0;
private int _round = 1;


protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);

    out.putInt("p_hit", _hit);
    out.putInt("p_round", _round );
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle in)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(in);

    _hit = in.getInt("p_hit");
    _round = in.getInt("p_round");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `putIntegerArrayList()` to store the data, and `getIntegerArrayList()` to retrieve it. However, you've declared your variables as `List<Integer>`, which doesn't satisfy the requirements of `putIntegerArrayList()`.

You have two choices. First, you can change how you've declared your variables so that they are explicitly `ArrayList`s, not just `List`s:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> _selectednumber= new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> _points = new ArrayList<>();
private int _hit= 0;
private int _round = 1;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);

    out.putInt("p_hit", _hit);
    out.putInt("p_round", _round );
    out.putIntegerArrayList("p_selectednumber", _selectednumber);
    out.putIntegerArrayList("p_points", _points);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle in)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(in);

    _hit = in.getInt("p_hit");
    _round = in.getInt("p_round");
    _selectednumber = in.getIntegerArrayList("p_selectednumber");
    _points = in.getIntegerArrayList("p_points");
}
```

Or, you can wrap your `List` instances with `new ArrayList<>()` when you try to put them into the bundle:

```
private List<Integer> _selectednumber= new ArrayList<>();
private List<Integer> _points = new ArrayList<>();
private int _hit= 0;
private int _round = 1;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);

    out.putInt("p_hit", _hit);
    out.putInt("p_round", _round );
    out.putIntegerArrayList("p_selectednumber", new ArrayList<>(_selectednumber));
    out.putIntegerArrayList("p_points", new ArrayList<>(_points));
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle in)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(in);

    _hit = in.getInt("p_hit");
    _round = in.getInt("p_round");
    _selectednumber = in.getIntegerArrayList("p_selectednumber");
    _points = in.getIntegerArrayList("p_points");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Below should work for you:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
    out.putInt("p_hit", _hit);
    out.putInt("p_round", _round);
    out.getIntegerArrayList("_selectednumber");
    out.getIntegerArrayList("_points");
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle in) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(in);
    _hit = in.getInt("p_hit");
    _round = in.getInt("p_round");
    _selectednumber = in.getIntegerArrayList("_selectednumber");
    _points = in.getIntegerArrayList("_points");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!